# Space of quadrics

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, projective-geometry, projective-space, quadrics

What does one mean when they say that a certain "subspace" of quadrics has dimension $d$?

Specifically, let $\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{C})\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^3(\mathbb{C})$ be given by $[X_0:X_1]\mapsto [X_0^3:X_0^2X_1: X_0X_1^2:X_1^3]=[Y_0:Y_1:Y_2:Y_3]$.  The image of this map is obviously contained in the zero locus of each of the three polynomials $Y_0Y_3-Y_1Y_2$, $Y_0Y_2-Y_1^2$, $Y_1Y_3-Y_2^2$. What does it mean that the space of quadrics that contain the image is three-dimensional? Do quadrics form a vector space or something? I can understand that the set of quadrics is closed under scalar multiplication, but what about addition? Also, if there is a notion of dimension, then there must be a notion of basis. Do the quadrics defined by the polynomials above form a basis of the space mentioned? Why or why not? And what is a basis in this case?

Comment: I have taken the liberty to correct the equation of your first quadric (which erroneously involved a non-existent $Y_4$)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The "space of quadrics" in $\mathbb P^3$ is the space of homogeneous polynomials in $\mathbb C[Y_0,Y_1,Y_2,Y_3]$ of degree $2$, and can be identified with the *vector space* of global sections $$V_2=H^0(\mathbb P^3,\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^3}(2)),$$ which has dimension $$\dim V_2=\binom{3+2}{3}=10.$$ The quadric surface corresponding to $f\in V_2$ is the projective variety $$V_+(f)=\{f=0\}\subset \mathbb P^3.$$

Let $C\subset \mathbb P^3$ be the image of the map $\mathbb P^1\to \mathbb P^3$ that you described. As you know this is a *twisted cubic curve*, which means it is a smooth rational degree $3$ curve in $\mathbb P^3$. Consider the exact sequence
$$0\to \mathscr I_C\to \mathcal O_{\mathbb P^3}\to \mathcal O_C\to 0$$
defining the closed immersion $C\subset \mathbb P^3$. Twisting by $\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^3}(2)$ and taking global sections yields a short exact sequence of vector spaces $$0\to H^0(\mathbb P^3,\mathscr I_C(2))\to V_2\to H^0(\mathbb P^3,\mathcal O_C(2))\to 0.$$
The kernel, $H^0(\mathbb P^3,\mathscr I_C(2))$, is the space of quadrics containing $C$. Indeed, the surjection $V_2\to H^0(\mathbb P^3,\mathcal O_C(2))$ is the restriction map $f\mapsto f|_C$, and a surface $V_+(f)$ contains $C$ if and only if its defining equation vanishes identically on $C$, i.e. $f|_C=0$. Since $$H^0(\mathbb P^3,\mathcal O_C(2))\cong H^0(\mathbb P^1,\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^1}(6))\cong\mathbb C^7,$$ the kernel $H^0(\mathbb P^3,\mathscr I_C(2))$ is indeed $3$-dimensional, generated by the sections you mention.

**Added** (Thanks Georges!): To show $V_2\to H^0(\mathbb P^3,\mathcal O_C(2))$ is surjective, we have to show that for every homogeneous polynomial $h(u,v)$ of degree $6$, there is a homogeneous polynomial $g(Y_0,Y_1,Y_2,Y_3)$ of degree $2$ such that $h(u,v)=g(u^3,u^2v,uv^2,v^3)$. The space containing the $h$'s is spanned by the monomials $h_i(u,v)=u^iv^{6-i}$, for $0\leq 0\leq 6$. We can divide by $3$ and write $$i=3p+q,\qquad 6-i=3p'+q',$$ with $0\leq q,q'\leq 2$ and $q+q'\equiv 0\bmod 3$. Then $h_i(u,v)=(u^3)^p(v^3)^{p'}u^qv^{q'}$. This direct argument can be found in [this paper by Ottaviani](http://web.math.unifi.it/users/ottavian/bcn.pdf), but generalizes to the statement that the rational normal curve in $\mathbb P^n$ is projectively normal, that is, it is normal and satisfies $H^1(\mathbb P^n,\mathscr I(d))=0$ for all $d\geq 0$. Another class of projective varieties $X\subset \mathbb P^r$ for which the restriction maps $H^0(\mathbb P^r,\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^r}(d))\to H^0(X,\mathcal O_{X}(d))$ are onto is that of complete intersections (which the twisted cubic is not).

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with sections, etc., and I was expecting a more elementary answer. Is it correct to say that the three equations in question form a basis of the minimal subspace of degree 2 homogeneous polynomials in 4 variables containing the image of the map in question?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. You can avoid the sheaf machinery to show that in the 10-dimensional space of homogeneous degree 2 polynomials (in $4$ variables), those vanishing on $C$ form a $3$-dimensional linear subspace.

Comment: Dear Brenin, maybe you could explain why the map  $V_2\to H^0(\mathbb P^3,\mathcal O_C(2))$ is surjective?

Comment: Thanks Georges, the argument was quite incomplete indeed.

Comment: Dear Brenin, thanks for the reference to Ottaviani. I was indeed thinking that you would invoke the  projective normality of the  rational  cubic curve (which the interested reader can check in exercise IV 3.4, page 315 in Hartshorne). However the proof you sketch  is pleasantly more elementary. So, bravo for your fine answer ! (And +1 of course)